# Scheme Multiple function Calls Error

Tags: scheme

I am working on this school assignment and i kept running into this issue in the last line of the code below. The error is list-ref: contract violation. So, i was hoping that i can get help rewriting that last line so that i am able to use recursion because i am not allowed to use loops or begin as part of the assignment.

```
(define (second lst)
  (cond [(and(list? lst)(not(null? lst)) (not(null? (cdr lst)))) (first (rest lst))]
        [else '()]))

(define (extract-helper lst size counter)
  (cond [(equal? size counter) counter]
        [else (second (list-ref lst counter))(extract-helper (list-ref lst (+ counter 1)) size (+ counter 1))]))
```

Comment: At a minimum, you need to include the code that triggers the error. Beyond that, you should include the precise text that results from running the program, and what you think it might mean.

Comment: Note that in your `else` clause you do two things. The `(second ...)` but since it is not the last expression the result is discarded and the result is just from `(extract-helper ...)` If `size` is the length then you see clear that you do `(list-ref lst (+ counter 1))` so that you might try to fetch one lement more than you can.

Comment: Yea Sylwester that is exactly the problem. but the problem i am running into is that extract-helper process a list of lists that is why i have two two things in the else part. And the function second only takes a list not a list of lists. I dont know how to do recursion and call second function in that same line

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained what this function is supposed to accomplish.